# Rename files in Batch script using parse string

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, file-rename

I am struggling to understand all command on Batch and I am facing an issue.

I have files like this:

```
Rimouski 04-01-2021.txt
Rimouski 05-01-2021.txt
Rimouski 06-01-2021.txt
Rimouski 07-01-2021.txt
Rimouski 08-01-2021.txt
```

And I want them rename like this:

```
Rimouski 2021-01-04.txt
Rimouski 2021-01-05.txt
Rimouski 2021-01-06.txt
Rimouski 2021-01-07.txt
Rimouski 2021-01-08.txt
```

I basically just want the date to be reversed.

I can not change the original name to delete the space, I have to do it with this exact name.

I know that I can go through the files with:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b "*.txt"') do ( )
```

And I should use the command `Ren`, but that is all I know.

I also would like a solution that I can use and reuse "everywhere". Something like parsing the string and change the pieces in the order I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `help for`, pay attention to `tokens`. Also `help set`, it allows you to set a variable equal to a substring of its input. So you basically want to use the for loop to split the file names on the space, which is the default delimiter, then pick apart the second token into Year, Month, Day variables, and then piece it all back together in the rename.

So first step is get the loop and file search working correctly:

```
@for /f "tokens=1,2" %%I in ('dir /A-d /b "* ??-??-????.txt"') do @echo %%I %%J
```

This yields the following in my test directory:

```
> test
Rimouski 04-01-2021.txt
Rimouski 04-02-2021.txt
Rimouski 04-03-2021.txt
Rimouski 04-04-2021.txt
```

And I have some other files in there, so I know it's filtering well enough.

Now parsing and putting things back to together, plus some script hygiene:

```
@setlocal EnableExtensions
@set prompt=$G

@for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%I in ('dir /A-d /b "* ??-??-????.txt"') do @call :DoIt "%%I" %%J %%K
@exit /b 0

:DoIt
@if "%~3" neq "" (@echo %1 does not match file filter. & exit /b 0)
@set "_prefix=%~1"
@set "_postfix=%~2"
@set "_dd=%_postfix:~0,2%"
@set "_mm=%_postfix:~3,2%"
@set "_yyyy=%_postfix:~6,4%"
@set "_ext=%_postfix:~10%"
@set "_newFileName=%_yyyy%-%_mm%-%_dd%%_ext%"
@echo ren "%_prefix% %_postfix%" "%_prefix% %_newFileName%"
@exit /b 0
```

All you have to do now is remove `@echo` from in front of the `@echo ren` line, and your ready to go. But test it first, make sure it's not trying to rename anything in your directory, that it's not supposed to rename.

Comment: Thank you ! Quick comments though, I got a syntax error on the "ren" function. I had to remove the "to" between the two parts. So: ren "%_prefix% %_postfix%" "%_prefix% %_newFileName%"

Comment: My bad. I initially just had it displaying what it would do.